# Ссылка  в div элементе, где у div z-index отрицательный

Tags: html, css

Есть одна картинка, она накладывается на div-элемент и должна быть ближе к пользователю по оси z. 
Но под ней есть блок div, с ссылками. Т.к. z-index  у него меньше, ссылки становятся неактивными.

Как справиться с этой ситуацией?

Что если создать ссылки отдельными элементами, и наложить их на предыдущий элемент. Т.е. применить margin-top  с минусом?

Comment: для всех браузеров [кроме любимого](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) есть свойство `pointer-evetns: none;`  еще можно копию элемента под картинками повесить над картинкой с opacity: 0

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/02/21/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx